# how to use Collections in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I need a VBA code for copying the red colored cell content (its value), its and sheet name for that cell and Paste into in the new sheet in the workbook.
For Example there is Workbook having 3 sheets into it. And every sheet contains cells marked in red. I want to copy the cell text, cell address and sheet for this and Paste into the new sheet.

Please help on this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What is your desired layout on the new sheet?  A: SheetName B:Value C:Row D:Column E:Range?  Or something like that?

Comment: I would reword your title for this post also.  Perhaps, "How to conditionally test for Cell color and report results" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you are looking for.  Just using simple loops,  first through the worksheets, then rows, then columns.

It will loop through all the worksheets in the workbook, exclude the master sheet, and examine the Interior color of the cell, and report to the Master sheet what the Sheet, Address, Value, Row, Columns are...

**TESTED:**

```
Sub ColorChecker()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim masterSheet As String
Dim mRow As Long
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long

mRow = 2
masterSheet = "Master"  'Set the name of the Master Sheet

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> masterSheet Then

            lastRow = Sheets(ws.Name).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
            lastCol = Sheets(ws.Name).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

            For lRow = 2 To lastRow
                For lCol = 1 To lastCol
                    If Sheets(ws.Name).Cells(lRow, lCol).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
                        Sheets(masterSheet).Cells(mRow, 1) = ws.Name
                        Sheets(masterSheet).Cells(mRow, 2) = LongToRange(lRow, lCol)
                        Sheets(masterSheet).Cells(mRow, 3) = Sheets(ws.Name).Cells(lRow, lCol).Value
                        Sheets(masterSheet).Cells(mRow, 4) = lRow
                        Sheets(masterSheet).Cells(mRow, 5) = lCol

                        mRow = mRow + 1
                    End If
                Next lCol
            Next lRow
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

**This function will create a named Range based on your Column and Row numbers.**

```
Function LongToRange(row As Long, col As Long) As String

Dim tempRange As String

tempRange = Chr(34) & ConvertToLetter(CInt(col)) & row & Chr(34)
LongToRange = tempRange

End Function
```

**This function is from [How to Convert Excel Column Numbers to Letters](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/833402)**

```
Function ConvertToLetter(iCol As Integer) As String
'FROM support.microsoft.com/kb/833404
   Dim iAlpha As Integer
   Dim iRemainder As Integer
   iAlpha = Int(iCol / 27)
   iRemainder = iCol - (iAlpha * 26)
   If iAlpha > 0 Then
      ConvertToLetter = Chr(iAlpha + 64)
   End If
   If iRemainder > 0 Then
      ConvertToLetter = ConvertToLetter & Chr(iRemainder + 64)
   End If
End Function
```

[image: Sheet1]
[image: Sheet2]
[image: Master]